# take input from console and parse in java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have to take "-4, 2, -5, 0, 3" as input from the console in java and need to store in an array[]. Where array[0]=-4, array[1] = 2 and so on .
I am completely new to java need immediate help.

Comment: `IntStream.generate(new Scanner(System.in)::nextInt).limit(5).toArray()`

Comment: We need to see an immediate attempt on your part to solve this problem. Start by reading [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `"-4, 2, -5, 0, 3".split(",\\s*")`

Comment: looks like a homework for me, why not you split the string and convert it to array

Comment: I am sorry If my question is not too clear. I am new to coding. Also, I am more comfortable with CPP and java is completely new to me. I am trying to solve a problem in java. So sorry if I pissed you off. But thanks a ton for those who helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 *
 * @author wathsara
 */
public class Example1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

        String a = s.nextLine();


        String[] b=(a.split(","));

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(b[i]); 

        }



    }


}
```

Try the above code. make sure you give the input in the form of 
-4,5,6,4,8 this way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, take the number of input from console then run the loop to get the inputs ,for example -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of input : ");
    Integer total = scanner.nextInt();

    Integer[] array =  new Integer[total];

    for (int i=0; i<total; i++) {
        array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    scanner.close();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is quite a bit to this, but assuming you have a way to read input, and you have that input as a String in your code already, and it's nicely formatted, then...

```
String input = "-4, 2, -5, 0, 3";
input.replaceAll("\\s","");       // Replaced all spaces/whitespace, now we have "-4,2,-5,0,3"
String[] arr = input.split(",")   // Split on the commas
System.out.println(arr[0]);       // Will print -4
System.out.println(arr[1]);       // Will print 2, etc.
```

Hope this helps!